# rackspace/mock_data error when running bundle exec rake test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I run bundle exec rake test I receive an error

```
/Users/joeyk16/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/fog-   1.23.0/lib/fog/rackspace/mock_data.rb:42: warning: duplicated key at line 80 ignored: "name"
Run options: --seed 21181
```

Any ideas. I have `run rake db:reset` nothing changed..

Answer (score 0):

It have duplicate name in source for key name:

```
 42       "name"  => "Ubuntu",
 80       "name"  => image_name,
```

File: `/gems/fog-1.23.0/lib/fog/rackspace/mock_data.rb`

Just delete line `42`.

Answer (score -2):

Upgrade your fog gem to the latest version, which you can find @ [RubyGems.org](https://rubygems.org/gems/fog). That should fix it for you.

Details:

1. Look up the latest version of fog gem @ [RubyGems.org](https://rubygems.org/gems/fog)
2. Replace the fog gem version number e.g. '1.23.0'  in the Gemfile by the latest version
3. run "bundle install" to update the gem
4. now bundle exec rake test should run

Comment: can you provide an explanation as to why you think updating the fog gem will resolve the issue? also, providing the link to RubyGems.org isn't particularly helpful, if you really think this will resolve the issue then I'd explicitly provide the command to perform the update, `gem update fog`

Comment: I ran into the same problem and updating the fog to 1.32.0 gem resolved the duplicate warning and allowed rake to run. The link is to check for the latest version. To update the gem I just changed the version number in the Gemfile.